# Cannot Connect To Server - Migration Parse Server iOS

Tags: node.js, swift, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I am following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/128313/parse-server-tutorial and I have successfully completed the steps to migrate my data to mLab as well as set up the parse-server.

I run this curl command

```
$ curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <myAppId>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{}' \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/_User
```

And it returns me JSON of all my users. After this step, the tutorial says to run the app and post some data. However this is where I get stuck, I get the following error code when trying to login, `[Error]: Could not connect to the server. (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)`. I configured my app key and my server url as instructed in the tutorial.

```
    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID"
    $0.clientKey = ""
    $0.server = "http://localhost:1337/parse"
}
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set env var VERBOSE=1 before start your parse-server, and see what the difference from your curl request and ios sdk.

Once a request receive, parse-server will show the logs of the request. If you havn't see any log after your ios-app send request. Check your ios-app serverUrl is correct.

The serverUrl on your ios-app should not be localhost. Localhost means your device, and it not host the parse server. You should change it to the IP(except 127.0.0.1) or the domain name which host the parse server. If your phone and the server connect to same wifi, you can use 192.168.x.x(ifconfig) to connect.

Comment: so it looks like it only works when i run in simulator because i havnt deployed it to heroku yet so i am not sure my device can connect.

Comment: @kareem ChunTingLin made a good point that localhost on your iPhone is the iPhone itself while localhost on your iOS Simulator is your Mac where the server runs. That is why your phone can't find a server to connect to. It is fairly easy to deploy the parser server to heroku. I suggest you try that and it is free if you start with a basic dyno.

Comment: @Manuel yeah, deploying to heroku did the trick! whats a good plan to use for a production app?

Comment: @kareem The required plan depends on your app needs. I experienced that a `Standard-2x` dyno on heroku can easily handle up to 100 requests/second to Parse Server.

Comment: @Manuel okay great and this is opposed to the free tier api.parse.com 30 request/second ?

Comment: @kareem Yes, it is 3 times the Parse.com free tier if you will.